# How to import state from redux slices as different variables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I have notification component which shows state of queries, so I need to import all states as different names in cause of many variables with same names

```
const { loading, success, error } = useAppSelector(state => state.messageReducer)
const { loading, success, error } = useAppSelector(state => state.offerReducer)
```

I want to do it like destructuring works:

```
const { customName, customName1, customName2 } = {loading, success, error}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { loading : basketLoading, success : basketSuccess, error: basketError } = useAppSelector(state => state.basketReducer)
```

It was pretty easy...